# css3 pie htc not working IE7 and IE6 (works in IE8)

Tags: css, css3pie

I am trying to get pie working to get rounded corners and gradients in all IE browsers 6+.

It is working in IE8, but for some reason not in IE7 or 6 - any ideas as to why?

Here is an example of my css element and html nothing special:

```
<style type="text/css">

#pietest{
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
background: #EEFF99;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
behavior: url('PIE.htc');
}

</style>

<div id="pietest"></div>
```

Comment: worked out that IE6 and 7 are not loading the PIE.htc but IE8 is - anyone know why this is?

Comment: When going to the pie.htc file in IE6 or 7 it has script errors - 'element' is undefined line 14 char 1

Comment: set position:relation , try this

Comment: I presume you mean position:relative. That makes no difference, Im sure it must be something to do with the script error I mentioned

Comment: Please up in online server may be it will work , Some times pie does not work in local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could never find a solution but managed to get pie.js working instead

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, I think it happens because the browser didn't treat the .htc file as a text/x-component. The official document has mentioned it [here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type)

So I believe we need to make the server set the content-type correctly.
Hope this will help u.

I add the mime type mapping in the web.xml to decare the htc as text/x-component,
then it work correctly.